# addPreferencesFromResource makes sharedPreferences not work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

So probably another newbish question :)

I have an `Activity`, an `AppWidgetProvider` and a `PreferenceActivity`. In the `PreferenceActivity` I have a `ListPreference` which I use to define the text-size for the widget. The `sharedPreferences` are loaded with no problems when the main activity starts, but as soon as the `PreferenceActivity` is run, I can no longer retrieve the `sharedPreference` values properly in the main activity. I tried retrieving the `sharedPreference` values directly in the `PreferenceActivity` and the same thing happened: For some reason when I try to get the values from the `sharedPreferences` BEFORE I call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.drawable.settings);` (at comment 'Test 1'), it says:

> "onStart() 1, size: small" and "Small works!"

I.e. it works. But when I try to retrieve the values AFTER the resource-call (at comment 'Test 2'), it says:

> "onStart() 2, size: small" and "It doesn't work ..."

I.e. it DOESN'T work. I have NO idea why. Obviously it gets the value of the `sharedPreference` as it says that the current `textWidgetSize` equals "small" in both cases, but for some reason it doesn't think that "small" = "small" after the resource-call. Do you guys have any idea what's wrong?

Here's the PreferenceActivity code:

```
package dk.mfoller.android.basicnote;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import dk.mfoller.android.basicnote.R;

public class BasicNoteSettings extends PreferenceActivity{

    String widgetTextSize = "small";
    boolean widgetLineCounter = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Calls a function to get the preferences
        getPrefs();

        // Test 1
        makeToast("onStart() 1, size: " + widgetTextSize);
        if(widgetTextSize == "small") {
            makeToast("Small works!");
        } else if(widgetTextSize == "medium") {
            makeToast("Medium works!");
        } else if(widgetTextSize == "large") {
            makeToast("Large works!");
        } else {
            makeToast("It doesn't work ...");
        }

        // Gets the preference layout from xml
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.drawable.settings);

        // Calls a function to get the preferences
        getPrefs();

        // Test 2
        makeToast("onStart() 2, size: " + widgetTextSize);
        if(widgetTextSize == "small") {
            makeToast("Small works!");
        } else if(widgetTextSize == "medium") {
            makeToast("Medium works!");
        } else if(widgetTextSize == "large") {
            makeToast("Large works!");
        } else {
            makeToast("It doesn't work ...");
        }

    }

    // A function to get the preferences    
    private void getPrefs() {
        // Gets data from the shared preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        widgetTextSize = prefs.getString("text_size_list", "small");
        widgetLineCounter = prefs.getBoolean("line_counter_cbox", true);
    }

    // A function to display a popup
    private void makeToast(String popup) {
        Toast.makeText(this, popup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Here's the xml-document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="basicnote_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings_label">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Text size">
        <ListPreference android:key="text_size_list"
        android:title="Widget text size"
        android:summary="@string/text_size_summary"
        android:entries="@array/text_size_options"
        android:entryValues="@array/text_size_values"
        android:defaultValue="small" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Other settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="line_counter_cbox"
            android:title="Line counter"
            android:summary="@string/hidden_lines_summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here are my resource strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Defines various resources -->
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">basicNote</string>
    <string name="note_hint">Tap to add some notes ...</string>
    <string name="fake_load">Loading notes ...</string>

    <string name="settings_label">basicNote settings</string>

    <string name="text_size_summary">Set the size of the widget text</string>
    <string-array name="text_size_options">
        <item>Small (12sp)</item>
        <item>Medium (13sp)</item>
        <item>Large (15sp)</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="text_size_values">
        <item>small</item>
        <item>medium</item>
        <item>large</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="hidden_lines_summary">Show/hide the number of lines not shown in the widget</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using == on a String object. Use .equals(yourString) instead.

Comment: You guys are FANTASTIC! That solved it - of course. I've spent days trying to figure this out.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

try to change all == in string compare to equals(). For example:

```
if(widgetTextSize.equals("small"))
{
}
```

and take a look at [this](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml) article